# Can't see files on external drive

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-4, filesystem, raspbian-lite

I'm using an external drive for my cloud storage. Everything was working fine and then I installed airsonic. I added the `tomcat8` user to the `www-data` group so that airsonic could see the music directory. All worked well and airsonic was scanning the files.

I came back later and the scan had stopped and airsonic was showing an error that the music directory could not be found. Using `ls -a` in the root of the drive I can't see any files, even as the root user. However, when I plugged the external disk into my desktop and did `ls -a` as the root user I was able to see that all of the files were still there. Why can't the pi see the files?

I'm using Raspbian Lite Stretch on Pi4. The disk is formatted as Ext4.

Edit: I've solved the problem. The drive wasn't mounted correctly. There was an error with the `fstab` config so after a reboot, the drive hadn't mounted.

Comment: Why not Raspbian Buster? The Raspberry Pi 4B is only supported by Raspbian Buster. || https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=249278

Comment: My mistake, I am using buster.

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk` on the Pi with the external disk connected and the system in the failed state?

Comment: Please don't add the solution you have found to the question. Instead make your own answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question. Otherwise it will pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the drive wasn't mounted correctly because of an error in the `fstab` config.